# How to call react router DOM link inside a function call/manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios, react-router-dom

The high level task I would like to do is to call a Link from react-router-dom inside a function call.

My use case: I have a submit button which once clicked calls a POST API. I want to check the response of the POST API and if it is successful call it will go to my Link to my successful submission page. If it is an error I would like to call the Link to my error page. One factor to consider is that the POST API takes about 2 seconds to respond.

Ideally I would like the Link component to not be directly on the submit button component. I would like to call a function once the button is clicked which contains the Link component after my API responds.

Here is my current code:

```
    function SubmitFcn(){

const submitPostAPI = (async () => {await axios({
//data passed 
})
      .then(function (response) {
//here is where I capture the API response
 })
      .catch(function (error) {});
  });

return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/SubmitPage" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
        <Button
           disabled={btnDisabled}
          id="submitButtonFormPOST"
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={submitPostAPI}
          data-testid="submitButtonelement"
        >
          {" "}
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Here is what I would like my code to resemble, the problem is it is not compiling because I am calling the Link component incorrectly.

```
  function SubmitFcn(){

const submitPostAPI = (async () => {await axios({
//data passed 
})
      .then(function (response) {
//here is where I capture the API response
LinkFunction(response.status)
 })
      .catch(function (error) {});
  });

return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/SubmitPage" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
        <Button
           disabled={btnDisabled}
          id="submitButtonFormPOST"
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={submitPostAPI}
          data-testid="submitButtonelement"
        >
          {" "}
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
}

function LinkStatus(result){
if(result === 201){
<Link to="/Submitsucess"/>}

else{
<Link to="/ErrorPage:/>
}
}
```

Comment: Are you *really* trying to programmatically navigate to one of two different routes depending on `submitPostAPI` result? Or are you simply just wanting to update the UI to provide the one of two links for a user to click on?

Comment: I want to navigate to one of the two different routes depending on the results of submitPostAPI. @DrewReese

Comment: Try using `history.push("/submitSuccess")` or `history.push("/errorPage")` via the `history` object provided from [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) or [`useHistory`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) react hook. If you update your question to include the component code/structure and where/how it's rendered within a route we can help more if getting to the `history` prop/object isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Use `history.push("/submitSuccess")` or `history.push("/errorPage")` via the `history` object provided from [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) or [`useHistory`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) react hook.

You likely may also want to remove the `Link` wrapping the button as that can interfere with *this* component remaining mounted.

If the component is directly rendered by a `Route` component then it receives the route props, so just access `history` from the props object

```
props.history
```

otherwise use the `useHistory` react hook

```
const history = useHistory();
```

So component could look similar to either of these

```
const MyComponent = ({ history }) => {
  const submitPostAPI = async () => {
    await axios({
      //data passed
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        linkStatus(response.status);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        history.push("/errorPage"); // <-- go to error page here as well
      });
  };

  function linkStatus(result) {
    if (result === 201) {
      history.push("/submitSuccess");
    } else {
      history.push("/errorPage");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        disabled={btnDisabled}
        id="submitButtonFormPOST"
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={submitPostAPI}
        data-testid="submitButtonelement"
        type="button"
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

or

```
const MyComponent = ( ) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const submitPostAPI = async () => {
    await axios({
      //data passed
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        linkStatus(response.status);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        history.push("/errorPage"); // <-- go to error page here as well
      });
  };

  function linkStatus(result) {
    if (result === 201) {
      history.push("/submitSuccess");
    } else {
      history.push("/errorPage");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        disabled={btnDisabled}
        id="submitButtonFormPOST"
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={submitPostAPI}
        data-testid="submitButtonelement"
        type="button"
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```